# What is the best way to keep design-time resources out of the build?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

Our specific project is for Windows Phone, but I assume this question applies equally to all xaml-based projects. We've got a bunch of image assets that are used at design-time only, and don't want them as part of the released build. If possible, we'd prefer they weren't part of `Debug` configuration builds, either. Does anyone have a best practice on how to go about doing this?

One solution is to continue including the images in the project, but set the Build Action to `None`. The problem with this is that it's easy to forget, since the default for images is to include them as `Content`.

Theoretically, another solution is to add these images to an assembly that's only referenced in Debug builds, but I haven't tested it out yet. I don't know if Blend or the VS designer will work well with that solution, and we'd rather not have the images as part of Debug builds anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use `DesignTime` data quite a bit and do exclude them from the release builds,

[Maximizing the Visual Designer’s Usage with Design-Time Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx) has a section at the very bottom "Excluding Design-Time Data from Production Builds" which works just fine for our requirements.

**Extracted from above link:**

> Excluding Design-Time Data from Production Builds
>   When handled carefully, the design-time code isn’t harmful to production applications (because it isn’t executed at run time), but excluding this code and all the corresponding assets (such as images) from the production build is still preferable.
>
> To do that, you need to modify the CSPROJ file manually with the following steps. There’s no other way to do this in the current version of Visual Studio 2012.

- Right-click on the project you want to edit in Solution Explorer.
- From the context menu, select Unload project.
- Right-click on the same project, and select Edit [project name].
- Locate the files you want to exclude, and for each file, add a Condition to the XML element in the CSPROJ file. For example, the DesignFriendsService can be excluded in Release mode with the code shown below.
- Close the CSPROJ file.
- Right-click on the unloaded project in Solution Explorer,

and select Reload Project.

```xml
<Compile Include="Design\DesignRssService.cs"
         Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' "/>
```

This condition can be set on all the design-time files, including pictures and other assets. The excluded items will still be visible in Solution Explorer, but they won’t be included in the final binary. In fact, if you build the solution after excluding the DesignRssService, you’ll get a compilation error in the ViewModelLocator.

You must enclose the lines of code that use the DesignRssService in precompiler directives as shown here:

```cs
if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
{
#if DEBUG
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRssService, Design.DesignRssService>();
#endif
}
else
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRssService, RssService>();
}
```